# Eloquent delete not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

This is my code :

Route

```
Route::resource('ItemName', 'ItemNameController');
```

Controller

```
public function destroy(ItemName $itemName)
{
    $itemName->delete();
    return redirect('ItemName')->with('success', 'Item Has Been Delete');
}
```

View

```
<form action="{{ route('ItemName', $ItemName->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method("DELETE")
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ $ItemName- 
    >id }}" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete 
    This Item? #{{ $ItemName->inc }} ')">
</form>
```

The problem is that code doesn't work to delete the item in table, any help? Thanks

Comment: You are getting any error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    ItemName::destroy($id); 
    return redirect('ItemName')->with('success', 'Item Has Been Delete');
}
```

or you could try

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $itemName = ItemName::find($id);
    $itemName ->delete(); 
    return redirect('ItemName')->with('success', 'Item Has Been Delete');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, your answer so helpful

Answer (score 1):

Change your view code like this

```
<form action="{{ route('ItemName', $ItemName->id) }}" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete 
    This Item? #{{ $ItemName->inc }} ')">
    @csrf
    @method("DELETE")
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Or also you can set action like this `action="url('/ItemName/'. $ItemName->id)"`